# API call with Java + STS returning "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported"

Tags: java, spring, rest, api-design

I am working on part of an API, which requires making a call to another external API to retrieve data for one of its functions. The call was returning an HTTP 500 error, with description "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported." The call is expected to return a type of 'application/json."

I found that this is because the response received doesn't explicitly specify a content type in its header, even though its content is formatted as JSON, so my API defaulted to assuming it was an octet stream.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to adjust for this. How would I get my API to treat the data it receives from the other API as an application/json even if the other API doesn't specify a content type? Changing the other API to include a contenttype attribute in its response is infeasible.

Code:
The API class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path={Constants.API_DISPATCH_PROFILE_CONTEXT_PATH},produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public class GetProfileApi {

    @Autowired
    private GetProfile GetProfile;

    @GetMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
    public Mono<GetProfileResponse> getProfile(@Valid @PathVariable String id){
        return GetProfile.getDispatchProfile(id);

    }
```

The service calling the external API:

```
@Autowired
private RestClient restClient;

@Value("${dispatch.api.get_profile}")
private String getDispatchProfileUrl;

@Override
public  Mono<GetProfileResponse> getDispatchProfile(String id) {

    return Mono.just(id)
                .flatMap(aLong -> {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    return restClient.get(getDispatchProfileUrl, headers);
                }).flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                    HttpStatus status = clientResponse.statusCode();
                    log.info("HTTP Status : {}", status.value());
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(GetProfileClientResponse.class);
                    // the code does not get past the above line before returning the error
                }).map(GetProfileClientResponse -> {
                    log.debug("Response : {}",GetProfileClientResponse);
                    String id = GetProfileClientResponse.getId();

                    log.info("SubscriberResponse Code : {}",id);
                    return GetProfileResponse.builder()
                            // builder call to be completed later
                            .build();
        }); 
}
```

The GET method for the RestClient:

```
public <T> Mono<ClientResponse> get(String baseURL, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers){
    log.info("Executing REST GET method for URL : {}",baseURL);

    WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
            .build();
    return client.get()
            .exchange();

}
```

One solution I had attempted was setting `produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}` in the `@RequestMapping` of the API to `produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE}`, but this caused a different error, HTTP 406 Not Acceptable. I found that the server could not give the client the data in a representation that was requested, but I could not figure out how to correct it.

How would I be able to treat the response as JSON successfully even though it does not come with a content type?

Hopefully I have framed my question well enough, I've kinda been thrust into this and I'm still trying to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using jackson library or jaxb library for marshalling/unmarshalling?

Try annotating Mono entity class with @XmlRootElement and see what happens.

Comment: I believe it is using Jackson. Annotating with `@XmlRootElement`  did not resolve to a type, so it doesn't seem to be in the project dependencies.